# Can't change my compiler from clang to gcc on mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal, homebrew

I'm following a tutorial on youtube to try and change my compilers from clang to gcc. It states that after installing gcc with homebrew, I can `cd /opt/homebrew/bin` and then run the commands:

```
ln -s gcc-11 gcc
ln -s g++-11 g++
```

After following all the steps, this is the furthest I have come.
In the terminal, typing `gcc --version` shows me that I am indeed using:

```
MacBook-Air ~ % gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

However, running `g++ --version` still shows clang:

```
MacBook-Air ~ % g++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

What am I doing wrong? I've followed multiple other forums and youtube videos and none of the commands are working on my device. FYI I'm working on a newly started Macbook air that literally has chrome and vscode and thats it.

Comment: apple maps `g++` to clang.  Not sure how to change that.  looking for a dupe

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler

Comment: Use complete path when soft-linking.

Comment: Does the brew gcc install the accompanying libstdc++? `brew info gcc` is not informative at all on the matter compared to `brew info llvm`. I'm asking because if it does, you have more work than that to do, and if it doesn't you're not going to get the full benefits of the newest gcc.

Comment: (not sure if this applies to macos) the original path to g++ might just be in your cache: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use this approach, you need to ensure that `/opt/homebrew/bin` appears in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`. You can check this with:

```bash
$ echo $PATH
```

Assuming you've ensured that, you can check for shell aliases with:

```bash
$ type g++
```

Another alternative that doesn't require messing with `$PATH` is to define shell aliases, eg:

```bash
$ alias gcc='gcc-11'
$ alias cc='gcc-11'
$ alias g++='g++-11'
$ alias c++='c++-11'
```

Comment: I checked my path, /opt/homebrew/bin did in fact appear before /usr/bin. Creating alias's did however solve my problem so for that, many thanks.